# How to use autocomplete with two textfields ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autocomplete, uitextfield, google-places

In my app i am having two `textFields`, by clicking each `textField` i can able to select places loading from google places autocomplete.In user handler i have to assign in which textfield i have to show the result.If i click first textfield, value showing second textfield vice versa.I set tag values for both textfields. Below is my full code.Thanks in advance.

```
//when first textfield clicked
- (IBAction)onLaunchClicked:(id)sender {
        GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
        acController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

//when second textfield clicked
- (IBAction)to_click:(id)sender {
        GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
        acController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


// Handle the user's selection.
    - (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
    didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        // Do something with the selected place.
        NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
        NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
        NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);

 //have to set values in correct textfields
    if (textfield.tag == 10001){
    from_txt.text=place.formattedAddress;
   }
    else {
    to_txt.text= place.formattedAddress;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare one more instance `textField` in your `viewController` like this

```
UITextField *selTextField;
```

Now set the reference of clicked textField to selTextField in your both `IBAction` like this

```
- (IBAction)onLaunchClicked:(id)sender {
    self.selTextField = (UITextField*) sender;
    GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
    acController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)to_click:(id)sender {
    self.selTextField = (UITextField*) sender;
    GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
    acController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now in delegate method of `GMSAutocompleteViewController`

```
- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    // Do something with the selected place.
    NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
    NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
    NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);

    //Set textField value
    self.selTextField.text=place.formattedAddress;
}
```

Comment: No, do not declare a global. Declare an instance variable. There is a huge difference.

Comment: @rmaddy Edited answer for instance variable.

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding :)